# error while loading new compiled Linux kernel image into the android emulator(1.5)

Tags: android-emulator, linux-kernel, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I have successfully compiled Linux kernel for android:

```
root@ubuntu:~/common# ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=~/mydroid/prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi- make 
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
make[1]: `include/asm-arm/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
.
.
.
 SYMLINK include/asm -> include/asm-arm
 CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
<stdin>:1097:2: warning: #warning syscall fadvise64 not implemented
<stdin>:1265:2: warning: #warning syscall migrate_pages not implemented
<stdin>:1321:2: warning: #warning syscall pselect6 not implemented
<stdin>:1325:2: warning: #warning syscall ppoll not implemented
<stdin>:1365:2: warning: #warning syscall epoll_pwait not implemented
  CHK     include/linux/compile.h
  Kernel: arch/arm/boot/Image is ready
  Kernel: arch/arm/boot/zImage is ready
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 157 modules
root@ubuntu:~/common#
```

but i get the following error while loading this images in the emulator:

```
root@ubuntu:~/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools# ./emulator -avd avd1.5 -kernel ~/common/arch/arm/boot/zImage -show-kernel -verbose
emulator: found SDK root at /home/preetam/android-sdk-linux_x86
emulator: root virtual device file at /home/preetam/.android/avd/avd1.5.ini
.
.
.
yaffs_read_super: isCheckpointed 0
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
# init: cannot find '/system/bin/playmp3', disabling 'bootsound'
init: cannot find '/system/bin/dbus-daemon', disabling 'dbus'
eth0: link up
init: untracked pid 578 exited
init: untracked pid 579 exited
warning: `rild' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
init: untracked pid 601 exited
init: untracked pid 592 exited
init: untracked pid 605 exited
init: untracked pid 602 exited
init: untracked pid 609 exited
init: untracked pid 606 exited
init: critical process 'servicemanager' exited 4 times in 4 minutes; rebooting into recovery mode
save exit: isCheckpointed 1
save exit: isCheckpointed 1
Restarting system with command 'recovery'.
Reboot failed -- System halted
```

and the emulator didn't start with the new kernel image(emulator didn't reboot). what is the problem here..?? and how can i replace my emulator's image with newly compiled Linux permanently??

please help. thank you!

Comment: Hi Preetam, I am having the exact same error. Could you help me? How did u solve it?

Answer (score 2):

i tried to load kernel image for android 2.1 into android 1.5...the image successfully loaded in 2.1