# how to reboot the emulator into recovery mode

Tags: android, reboot

is there any way to reboot the emulator into recovery mode??

Comment: what do you mean by recovery mode?

Comment: i want to flash the android kernel image, so i need to reboot in the recovery mode. the android phones can be rebooted, but not emulators, dont understand why... please check this thread, at last the emuator tried to reboot into recovery mode. and it failed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406549/error-while-loading-new-compiled-linux-kernel-image-into-the-android-emulator1-5

Comment: i have compiled linux kernel for android, and i want to install it in android emulator 1.5. please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android kernel compile and test with Android Emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809774/android-kernel-compile-and-test-with-android-emulator)

Comment: thankyou very much. that was very helpful. please ans this:   i don't understand what am i doing wrong:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406549/error-while-loading-new-compiled-linux-kernel-image-into-the-android-emulator1-5

Comment: @Macarse: An android system can normally boot in three modes, normal mode, recovery mode where the linux kernel is booted but with an alternative root file system, and typically only starting adb and a recovery tool, and last in can be booted in a fastboot/bootloader mode, allowing flashing of signed images to the device.

Comment: related https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/82905/boot-android-virtual-device-into-recovery-mode

Answer (score 11):

- Android emulator does not support recovery mode, just normal boot mode
- Android emulator accepts Android images -including kernel and ramdisk images - as standalone images on it's command line interface. They are not compiled to one big image as in a real world scenario where all Android partitions are stored to the same phone storage
- The kernel of Android emulator is a custom build of a android kernel, it's called goldfish kernel which can communicate with the virtual  platform developed by Google engineers named as "goldfish", a pre-built of this kernel can be found under $sdk/system-images/android-22/default/armeabi-v7a/kernel-qemu
  Please note you can not just replace it by kernels other than goldfish kernels. However, goldfish kernel source code can be found @ gooogle repo and can be easily compiled and replaced by the default one that comes with the Android SDK
- In case you need to run the android emulator with another Linux kernel, then you have to port this kernel to the golfish virtual hardware (which is not a straight-forward process). I did it before and I can elaborate more on how to do it if needed.
- In order to boot the android emulator in the recovery mode, you need to do an extra effort of porting a tool called "u-boot" (i.e. a well-known and widely used 2nd stage boot-loader used in real phones) to the goldish virtual board to be able to run it on top of android emulator. I did that a couple of years ago and it was very mind-blowing process. I can provide you with tremendous information if you are interested in doing so.