# Monitor all HTTP traffic to and from an Android phone

Tags: android, http, filter

I want to make an app that can block all explicit HTTP content on an Android device. The problem is that it would have to block traffic **on the phone**, not just from a specific app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a similiar question asked on stackoverflow here:

[iptables in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577268/iptables-in-android)

i.e. It is possible using hooks to iptables.  However the problem is getting access to iptables. Read the link for further information.