# how to run droidwall on my emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, iptables

when i am trying to run droid wall application in my 2.3 emulator it shows some error

```
Error applying iptable rules.
exit code3
iptable v1.4.10
iptable v1.4.10:
cant inialize iptable 'Filter':
Table need no exist(Do you need insmod?) perhaps iptables or your kernel need to be upgraded.
```

how to solve this issue

Comment: droidwall requires a rooted device.  Have you installed a rooted emulator AVD?

Comment: i followed the http://allencch.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/learn-to-root-android-using-emulator/  link and manage to get rooted emulator , using rootcheckpro.apk verified the root and it shows device is rooted

Comment: My guess is you need to add iptables to your AVD.  I am not sure how to do that, but you can look through [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577268/iptables-in-android) for possible answers.

Answer (score 0):

Droidwall is an app that processes iptables , sets rules and chains to control network permissions to app in the android device. It needs root access to set rules to iptables .
So, your device must be rooted for the purpose. Emulators dont have root privilages and so you cant run droidwall on it.

Comment: There are methods of getting a [rooted AVD](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1731095).