# Is it possible to monitor HTTP traffic on Android knowing which application generated requests?

Tags: android, http, networking, sniffing

I was asked to make an Android app which among other things must monitor incoming and outgoing HTTP traffic for a set of applications installed on the device.
The idea is that a log must be generated with:

App: xxx requested URL: yyy response from server was: zzz
and so on

I don't think this is possible at all, without customizing the rom and doing some sorcery in there, but even customizing the rom I cannot think of a way to do this, anyone has suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Also see [iptables in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577268/iptables-in-android)